# JQuery is not working in JSP with Struts2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have included the JQuery CDN in the `<script>` tag,but it does not works. I am using intellij, it prompts me WITH such warning "Unresolved function or method $()"

Any response is appreciated

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>Success</title>
    <script>
        $("#select").click(function() {
            alert("aaaa");
        });
        $("#delete").click(function() {
            alert("aa");
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="person">personname</label>
<input id="person" name = "person" type="text" />
<input id="add"type="button" value="add" />
<input id="delete"type="button" value="delete"/>
<input id="select"type="button" value="select"/>
<input id="update"type="button" value="update"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DaveNewton well... that is the latest version of JQuery that is compatible with IE < 9

Comment: @DaveNewton that's the latest jQuery 1.x. it is 2015. Is jQuery 1.x considered old in USA (just curious) ? I guess the IE 8-9-10 EOL notice of one week ago could push things toward jQuery 2, but considering 1.12 an *old* version sounds weird to me. They (jQuery 1 and 2) are parallel projects, aren't they ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios Hm, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have put all js inside header you have to put it inside `document.ready`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#select").click(function() {
            alert("aaaa");
        });
        $("#delete").click(function() {
            alert("aa");
        });

})
</script>
```

This is because `script` tag is a blocking tag and when you put it inside header tag, it will be parsed before DOM is ready. At that time jQuery don't know what is `#select` & `#delete`, so no way it will able to attach the `click` handler.

A second option is to put all script near closing body tag. So first DOM will be ready with elements then js will be executed. Then you can remove the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
})
```

Example

```
<body>
    <!--All HTML elements-->
    <script>
        // All your js goes here.
    </script>
```

There are several advantage of putting scripts just before closing `</body>` tag , which is beyond this question

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!